# Installshield - Force file to create on application path

Tags: installation, windows-installer, file-permissions, installshield

How to force folders and files to create on install direction?

I've installed a program with Install shield that create some folders and files. Some of files are going to create after installation (like log.dat , etc). Actually their path is not install path and they will create on setup.exe's path. I've added Everyone permission to [CompanyName] but it's still not working.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I appreciate that English may not be your first language. I want to help you but I can't understand your question.  Can you please get someone to assist you in editing your question for clarity?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Thanks a lot for your comment. I edited my question. Do you understand what is the problem?

Comment: I think you are saying your application (running in the user context) needs to be able to create files and folders after the installation is  done and that you are trying to relax the permissions to be able to do so.  Is that correct?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Yes.  The point is that files and folders were created by my program are not located at the [InstallDir] place and they were locate at near setup.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question,  I wouldn't open up the permissions in C:\Program Files... because that leaves up the possibility of a non-privileged user corrupting your application.   Instead I would use a directory such as [CommonAppDataFolder]\My Company\My Product  (C:\ProgramData\My Company\My Product typically)  and open up the permissions there.

InstallShield has the ability to create and assign permissions to directories.  It should be straight forward.  See:

[Configuring Permissions for Files and Folders](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/ConfiguringPrmssnsFile.htm)

Edit:   You say not INSTALLDIR but 'near' the  directory that contains SETUP.EXE.  InstallShield sets a property called SETUPEXEDIR that you can use.  But I'm not sure this design can work.  A user could run the installer from practically anywhere including a network share that the Windows Installer service couldn't possibly have permissions to.   I'm afraid your question is unanswerable beyond how to set the permissions in general.